# Responsive layout issue

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am trying to work towards a responsive design for a web app we are building.

The image below shows a prototype of what I am working on, taken from the jsfiddle below it.

Rather than the grey blocks folding under each other I want them to continue on horizontally causing a scroll if it goes out of view.

I used Erskine's gridpak to generate the responsive grid for me. Is there any way of achieving the effect using the current grid? I am at a bit of a stand still with it.

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/brendan_rice/wT8MG/

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it with `white-space:nowrap` and `display:inline-block`.

http://jsfiddle.net/wT8MG/7/

I removed the white space between the blocks to eliminate the extra margin caused by a space being rendered, one of the few drawbacks of inline-block.

If you want just the row to scroll and not the whole page then add `overflow-x:scroll` to the `main` or `row` class.

**EDIT:**

<del>For IE7 support add `<!--[if lt IE 8]> <style>.col{display:inline}</style> <![endif]-->` below the CSS.</del>

Ok, IE tricked me by keeping the document mode in IE8 standards when I switched the browser mode to IE7.

The CSS so far that will work in IE8+. Edited for brevity.

```
.side-panel {height: 300px}
.side-panel .container{background-color: blue;}
.main {
    width: 100%;
    white-space:nowrap
}
.container {background-color: #ddd;height: 30px;margin-top: 10px;}
.col {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    white-space:normal;
    border:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background-clip:padding-box !important;
}

@media screen{
    .col {
        margin-left:1%;
        padding:0 0%;
    }
    .row .col:first-child {margin-left:0;}
    .span_1 {width:19.2%;}
    .span_2 {width:39.4%;}
    .span_3 {width:59.6%;}
    .span_4 {width:79.8%;}
    .span_5 {margin-left:0;width:100%;}
}
```

Comment: I thought about using this, but it totally breaks down in IE8 and below.

Comment: To fix that add a conditional IE block for it. `<!--[if lt IE 9]> <style>.col{display:inline}</style> <![endif]-->`

Comment: That still doesn't fix it. Try it for yourself.

Comment: Whoops! Forgot IE8 supports inline-block. Change the conditional statement to `<!--[if lt IE 8]> <style>.col{display:inline}</style> <![endif]-->` and all should we good.

Comment: Your **edit** for IE7 does not work and the original code does not support IE8 either. Just test the fiddle in those environments and you will see that the code displays incorrectly.

Comment: I have and it does support IE8. I was mistaken about IE7. IE decided to stay in IE8 standards mode even though I switched the browser mode to IE7.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of a responsive grid is that you shouldn't ever have to horizontally scroll.

Percentages are relative to their parents. So no matter what width you set for `<div class="main row">`, each of your columns will always be a percentage of the total.

So if we add up all your columns, we get `(8 cols x (19.2% width + 1% margin)) - 1% remove first margin = 160.6%`. Floated elements always fold to the next line when they are larger than their parents, and as it will always be larger than its parent, it cannot help but fold. The only way to have them all on one line would be to have the total width of the columns add up to 100% or less of its parent container.

Comment: Thanks tw, I have just figured that out. It is more of an adaptive technique I need with pixel widths for the containers